# Run a command when apache restarts

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, centos7

I want to run a command "chmod -R 777 foldername" every time when apache restarts on my linux server.

How can I do that?

I have Linux CentOs 7.1 64 bit installed on my server with VestaCp.

Comment: Either you're the one person on earth with a case-insensitive shell, or you wrote this "CHMOD" command you're talking about. Incidentally, it's considered a Bad Idea(TM) to have multiple programs whose names differ only by case. Also, you can't possibly be running Apache 2.2 *and* 2.4. I'd guess with a fair degree of certainty you're using 2.4.

Comment: Hahaha! Sorry! I meant chmod, I don't know why I wrote it in uppercase :/
Yes, I have 2.4 running.

Comment: FWIW you almost certainly don't want to run chmod -R 777.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `/etc/init.d/apache2`

and add your command in start & restart

```
start)
            [..]
            CHMOD -R 77 foldername &
            ;;

restart)
            [..]
            CHMOD -R 77 foldername &
            ;;
```

But don't forget that thoose informations will be reset if there is an Apache update

Comment: I went to /etc/init.d folder but found no apache2 or httpd file. On doing 'ls', these were the folders and files in /etc/init.d/ :

functions  netconsole  network  README  vesta

Comment: did you checked in /etc/rc*.d/ ?

Comment: rc*.d has the following folders :
K50netconsole  S10network  S85vesta

Comment: CentOS 7 doesn't use init scripts

Comment: So, then how can can I edit the apache start script on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Redhat-style distros, but in Debian-likes there's */etc/default/apache2*, a shell file included on every run of */etc/init.d/apache2*.